# DataTables Ajax Error in django

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am doing some server-side ajax loading in django.

Here is my code clip:

```
@login_required
def cmdb_list_page_server_side(request):
#do not prepare data in view (as in  above view), data will be retrieved using ajax call (see get_countries_list below).
    return render_to_response('cmdb/list.html', locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def get_cmdb_list(request):
    #prepare the params

    #initial querySet
    querySet = CMDB.objects.all()
    #columnIndexNameMap is required for correct sorting behavior
    columnIndexNameMap = {
        0:'envcode',
        1:'appname',
        2:'sysip',
        3   :'ostype',
        4   :'hostname',
        5   :'cpu',
        6   :'mem',
        7   :'rootdisk',
        8   :'storagetype',
        9   :'location',
        10  :'enclosure',
        11  :'position1',
        12  :'position2',
        13  :'unit',
        14  :'serviceIP',
        15  :'manufacture',
        16  :'seller',
        17  :'machinemodel',
        18  :'machinecode',
        19  :'serialnumber',
        20  :'appearance',
        21  :'archtype',
        22  :'partition',
        23  :'storagesize',
        24  :'applevel',
        25  :'domains',
        26  :'netnote',
        27  :'gateway',
        28  :'mask',
        29  :'serviceport',
        30  :'ha',
        31  :'hbIP1',
        32  :'hbIP2',
        33  :'hardwarecharge',
        34  :'systemcharge',
        35  :'appcharge',
        36  :'managegateway',
        37  :'managemask',
        38  :'repairlevel',
        39  :'repairdate',
        40  :'dbinfo',
        41  :'middlewareinfo',
        42  :'nonsysusers',
        43  :'note',
    }
    #path to template used to generate json (optional)
    jsonTemplatePath = 'cmdb/json_cmdb.txt'

    #call to generic function from utils
    return get_datatables_records(request, querySet, columnIndexNameMap,jsonTemplatePath)
```

**the file "'cmdb/json_cmdb.txt" looks like this:**

```
{
    sEcho: {{sEcho}},
    iTotalRecords: {{iTotalRecords}},
    iTotalDisplayRecords: {{iTotalDisplayRecords}},
    aaData:[
        {% for item in querySet %}
        [
            "{{ item.envcode }}",
            "{{ item.appname }}",
            "{{ item.sysip }}",
            "{{ item.ostype }}",
            "{{ item.hostname }}",
            "{{ item.cpu }}",
            "{{ item.mem }}",
            "{{ item.rootdisk }}",
            "{{ item.storagetype }}",
            "{{ item.location }}",
            "{{ item.enclosure }}",
            "{{ item.position1 }}",
            "{{ item.position2 }}",
            "{{ item.unit }}",
            "{{ item.serviceIP }}",
            "{{ item.manufacture }}",
            "{{ item.seller }}",
            "{{ item.machinemodel }}",
            "{{ item.machinecode }}",
            "{{ item.serialnumber }}",
            "{{ item.appearance }}",
            "{{ item.archtype }}",
            "{{ item.partition }}",
            "{{ item.storagesize }}",
            "{{ item.applevel }}",
            "{{ item.domains }}",
            "{{ item.netnote }}",
            "{{ item.gateway }}",
            "{{ item.mask }}",
            "{{ item.serviceport }}",
            "{{ item.ha }}",
            "{{ item.hbIP1 }}",
            "{{ item.hbIP2 }}",
            "{{ item.hardwarecharge }}",
            "{{ item.systemcharge }}",
            "{{ item.appcharge }}",
            "{{ item.managegateway }}",
            "{{ item.managemask }}",
            "{{ item.repairlevel }}",
            "{{ item.repairdate }}",
            "{{ item.note }}",
            "{{ item.dbinfo }}",
            "{{ item.middlewareinfo }}",
            "{{ item.nonsysusers }}",
        ]
            {% if not forloop.last %}
                ,
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    ]
}
```

**Finally, I got error alert window from webbrowser(Chrome) saying datatables formatting error. 
Using firebug, i got error message as below:**

P.S My ajax returning value contains Chinese. I am wondering this is the root cause.
Ajax return as below:

```
{
    sEcho: 1,
    iTotalRecords: 1178,
    iTotalDisplayRecords: 1178,
    aaData:"[

        [
            "",
            "王晴测试机(临时)",
            "197.1.5.206",
            "windows 2003 64bit",
            "FANGLTST",
            "4",
            "32",
            "100G",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "0",
            "False",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "None",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
        ]

                ,


        [
            "",
            "Opsware测试",
            "197.1.4.201",
            "Redhat 64bit",
            "bsae",
            "1",
            "1",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "0",
            "False",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "None",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
        ]

                ,


        [
            "",
            "预留分区",
            "N/A",
            "AIX 6.1",
            "N/A",
            "4",
            "32",
            "100G",
            "",
            "兆维II",
            "ZWII-B1-08",
            "DOWN",
            "S13/14",
            "",
            "199.0.34.173",
            "IBM",
            "志鸿英华",
            "PS702",
            "8406",
            "06DB59A",
            "刀片",
            "小型机",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "255.255.255.0",
            "0",
            "False",
            "",
            "",
            "陈晓峰/毕伟光",
            "姜晓寒",
            "张元泉",
            "199.0.34.250",
            "255.255.255.0",
            "7*24*4",
            "None",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
        ]

                ,


        [
            "",
            "Opsware测试",
            "197.1.4.202",
            "Redhat 64bit",
            "hpna",
            "8",
            "16",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "0",
            "False",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "None",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
        ]

                ,


        [
            "",
            "预留分区",
            "",
            "AIX 6.1",
            "N/A",
            "2",
            "16",
            "100G",
            "",
            "兆维II",
            "ZWII-B1-08",
            "DOWN",
            "S13/14",
            "",
            "199.0.34.173",
            "IBM",
            "志鸿英华",
            "PS702",
            "8406",
            "06DB59A",
            "刀片",
            "小型机",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "255.255.255.0",
            "0",
            "False",
            "",
            "",
            "陈晓峰/毕伟光",
            "姜晓寒",
            "张元泉",
            "199.0.34.250",
            "255.255.255.0",
            "7*24*4",
            "None",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
        ]

                ,


        [
            "",
            "Opsware测试",
            "197.1.4.122",
            "",
            "opsware2",
            "0",
            "0",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "0",
            "False",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "None",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
        ]

                ,


        [
            "",
            "开发机",
            "197.1.4.18",
            "HPUX 11.23",
            "cmbcux1",
            "4",
            "8",
            "2*300G",
            "",
            "兆维",
            "ZW-01-01",
            "N/A",
            "",
            "U16/19",
            "197.1.7.205",
            "HP",
            "志鸿英华",
            "rx4640",
            "AB370B",
            "SGH4617B1X",
            "标准机架",
            "小型机",
            "N/A",
            "",
            "",
            "内联",
            "",
            "197.1.4.250",
            "255.255.255.0",
            "0",
            "False",
            "",
            "",
            "杨杰",
            "张立新",
            "张小龙",
            "197.1.7.250",
            "255.255.255.0",
            "N/A",
            "十一月 19, 2009",
            "sapcool1",
            "DB2 9.5.0.5",
            "",
            "",
        ]

                ,


        [
            "",
            "Opsware测试",
            "197.1.4.123",
            "",
            "opsware3",
            "0",
            "0",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "0",
            "False",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "None",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
        ]

                ,


        [
            "",
            "开发机",
            "197.1.4.24",
            "HPUX 11.23",
            "hpux3",
            "4",
            "8",
            "6*146G",
            "",
            "兆维",
            "ZW-01-01",
            "N/A",
            "",
            "U1/8",
            "197.1.7.206",
            "HP",
            "志鸿英华",
            "rx6600",
            "AD132A",
            "SGH4711KDR",
            "标准机架",
            "小型机",
            "N/A",
            "",
            "",
            "内联",
            "",
            "197.1.4.250",
            "255.255.255.0",
            "0",
            "False",
            "",
            "",
            "杨杰",
            "张立新",
            "胡汝能",
            "197.1.7.250",
            "255.255.255.0",
            "N/A",
            "四月 13, 2010",
            "None",
            "&quot;DB2 9.1.0.1",
            "None",
            "None",
        ]

                ,


        [
            "",
            "Opsware测试",
            "197.1.4.127",
            "",
            "opsware4bb",
            "0",
            "0",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "0",
            "False",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "None",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "",
        ]


    ]
}
```

Comment: hmmm could you post the entire error? also if you explain exactly what you are trying to achieve I am sure we can help you out a lot more since this solution seems to be overcomplicated (and full of empty values)

Comment: @Hassek Hi, thanks for your reply! I have solved this question. There was indeed format error :**"{{ item.nonsysusers }}", **where comma should be deleted... Too many fields there...